# after login it is not showing customer name in header

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

after login it is not showing customer name in header
[image]

Comment: It's may be page cache issue. Just one time disable page cache and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue should arrive from custom extension login session issue so you can check custom extension in your site and set some session code to perticuler file(may be from some custom extension) **"Hop this will help you!!"**